# How to cut out everything from a string except certain part of it in php?

Tags: php, html, string, variables

Let's say I have string like this:

```
Village_name(315|431 K64)
```

What I want to do is when I paste that into let's say text box, and click a button,  all I will be left with is `315|431`.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Well, can you define a global "cutting" rule or can it be different for several string ?

Comment: Any patterns? Do you want to get two 3-digit numbers beside the `|` character?

Comment: Please post what you have tried.  You will likely get more help if you show some effort.

Comment: You need to give a little more details. Does it always say "Village_name", is there always parenthesis? Is the ` K64` static?

Comment: Maybe you want to use javascript regex?

Comment: The structure of the string is always village_name(XXX|YYY KZZ)
where village_name can vary, xxx and yyy are always 3-digit numbers, K is static but ZZ is not. al I want is string containing XXX|yyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:-

```
<?php

   $str = 'Village_name(315|431 K64)';
   preg_match_all('/(?:\d+\|\d+)/', $str, $matches);
   echo "<pre/>";print_r($matches);//print in array format completly
   $i=0;
   foreach($matches as $match){ //iteration through one foreach as you asked
       echo $match[$i];
      $i++;
   }
?>
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/74ddg9

Note:- explode can work with some adjustment but if the format only like what you given.So go for `preg_match_all`. It's best.

Comment: I'll try that, looks like it is gonna work. The only thing though - I should iterate over the array and then iterate over the internal array to get the value, is that right? (two foreach loops, one nested into the other)

Comment: Not two foreach. one is enough. check my edited answer.

Comment: Welcome always :::)))

Answer (score 2):

Use the below regex and then replace the match with `\1`.

```
(\d+\|\d+)|.
```

It captures the `number|number` part and matches all the remaining chars. By replacing all the matched chars with `\1` will give you the `number|number` part only.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kQ0iM6/4)

In php, you may use this also.

```
(?:\d+\|\d+)(*SKIP)(*F)|.
```

substring which was matched by `\d+\|\d+` regex would be matched first and the following `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes the regex to fail. Now thw `.` after the pipe symbol would match all the chars except `number|number` because we already skipped that part.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kQ0iM6/5)

Comment: this looks interesting, but I have yet another question:
would it be enough if I paste (?:\d+\|\d+)(*SKIP)(*F)|. inside the code?
and also I would kindly ask for the function to trim white spaces leftover. Please and thank you :)

Comment: see I want to integrate it to my php script and from what you have given me I have no idea what piece of code should I use. It looks very interesting though

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been answered and the answer has been accepted. But I still want to suggest this answer, as you really don't need to use PHP to realize your requirement. Just use Javascript. Its enough:

```
var str = 'Village_name(315|431 K64)';
var pattern = /\((\w+\|\w+) /;
var res = str.match(pattern);
document.write(res[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I wanted to do it through php, as I mentioned in one of the comments, I want to integrate this into my existing php script, but thank you, It's good to know there are alternatives.